# DNS split horizon without copy

Tags: dns

I have a authoritative DNS server for my zone somewhere in the cloud.

Now there is the need to deliver a few records of this zone with local addresses in an internal network (only there). Classic split horizon I think.

Is there a way WITHOUT COPYING the complete zone to achieve this?

This comes from an old setup of the network and I have no influence to the need for the internal view.

Ideas:
internal DNS server with a few records and:

- Resolver that checks for NXDOMAIN intern and than forwards to extern
- internal DNS server with dnsdist and "some" rule

Comment: You can do this with bind running on your local network. Interested?

Comment: hmmm it is worth a try. I have a powerdns running internally (with the few local records) and its configured by some system but if a bind could be "in the middle" it could be a working solution

Comment: Ok unless someone else beats me to it I'll put something together today or tomorrow

Comment: A dnsmasq seems like the simplest solution. The `--address=/example/ipaddress` (used in configuration files without the `--`) allows to resolve all `example` requests from the given `ipaddress` (which could be the ip of your DNS server). No copying involved. Of course, any other dns server at any chosen port could be setup to re-produce your DNS server answers, and that could be the `ipaddress` for `dnsmasq`. In this latter case an AXFR could copy the dns database without any manual intervention. Even more complex setups are possible. Interested?

Comment: I think I would still need to provide a complete zone (so copy all entries) at the server "ipaddress" (just to call it like that). I cant why this would solve the problem.

Comment: If you are answering to my comment: there is a function called `alias` in dnsmasq to re-write answers (ip addresses) from upstream dns servers to local addresses.@muebau

Comment: I think the phrase I was looking for might be "NXDOMIAN hijacking". It is done for bad things usually but could solve my problem.

Comment: @QuartzCristal yes I answered to your comment. I do not fully understand what do you mean with that. Does it check server A (internal) first and tries server B (resolver) if server A gave a NXDOMAIN?

Comment: What I mean is that you can redirect (with dnsmasq and using an address directive) all queries of the internal domain name to the external DNS server that you already have set up. There are other alternatives. The main point is: you can use the external DNS server to resolve internal addresses. It is not a simple task, you do need to know what you are doing. @muebau

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is CoreDNS with the alternate plugin (https://coredns.io/explugins/alternate/).

A simple Docker container solved all my issues.

```
FROM golang:1.18 AS corednsbuilder

RUN git clone https://github.com/coredns/coredns.git /git

WORKDIR /git
RUN (echo "alternate:github.com/coredns/alternate" && cat /git/plugin.cfg) > /git/plugin.cfg.tmp && mv plugin.cfg.tmp plugin.cfg
RUN cd /git; make

FROM debian:stable-slim AS certs
SHELL [ "/bin/sh", "-ec" ]

RUN export DEBCONF_NONINTERACTIVE_SEEN=true \
       DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
       DEBIAN_PRIORITY=critical \
       TERM=linux ; \
apt-get -qq update ; \
apt-get -yyqq upgrade ; \
apt-get -yyqq install ca-certificates ; \
apt-get clean

FROM scratch

COPY --from=certs /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/
COPY --from=corednsbuilder /git/coredns /coredns

EXPOSE 53 53/udp
ENTRYPOINT ["/coredns"]
```

The config looks like this:

```
. {
    forward . 192.168.1.254
    alternate original NXDOMAIN,SERVFAIL,REFUSED . 1.1.1.1:53
    log
}
```

This way 192.168.1.254 is always asked and if it returns one of NXDOMAIN,SERVFAIL,REFUSED the request is forwarded (untouched) to 1.1.1.1:53